# work with xlsx files without saving in local memory

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc

I send .xlsx files in a POST request. In my JAVA code I want to read this files without saving in local memory. How can I do this, I've tried to create InputStream from obtained String object, but it throws exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source
```

my jsp button looks like that

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
      <button ng-click="ctrl.add()">Add</button>
```

my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody String s,    UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream); // here is Exception
    //... some working code
}
```

I am new in Spring and in working with .xlsx files, sorry if my question is quite stupid.

my angular snippet, where is sending part

```
function createFile(file) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post(REST_SERVICE_URI1, file)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while creating File');
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

(as extended explanation)
if i try to place InputStream instead of String i've got

```
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4fbc26a; line: 1, column: 14]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'PK ': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

Also question is: What is way to work with such files gotten from clients? 
I know that I should store them in my database as rows (this is part of my task), but should I create a temporary file to store them, in order then to load them in a database?

Comment: Don't send binary data as a `String`. It's curious how binary vs. text seems to be unclear to newer programmers.

Comment: Okey, maybe then problem in angular part of code. I'll add some snippet from angular.

Comment: No, the problem is visible in there, where your `@RequestBody` is a `String`.

Comment: i was trying other classes. Problem is I haven't experience dealing with such issue, how can i tackle with it? What should be instead String?

Comment: Put an `InputStream` as the parameter.

Comment: i was trying to use it already. 

i've got 
```
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4fbc26a; line: 1, column: 14]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'PK    ': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```